# Triggers compuestos en MySQL, error de syntaxis?

Tags: mysql, terminal

Estoy copiando el código tal cual lo hace el profesor (creo) y me devuelve que tengo un error de syntaxis...

Paso a explicar la idea del ejercicio por si ayuda:
Tengo 2 tablas, "drivers" y "active_drivers", y cuando el atributo "status" de un conductos de la tabla "drivers" cambia a 1 (que significa que el conductor esta trabajando) dicho conductor tiene que ser ingresado en la tabla "active_drivers". Si cambia a cero, su registro de la tabla "active_drivers" tiene que desaparecer porque significa que no esta activo.
Este es el código:

```
DELIMITTER //

CREATE TRIGGER update_active_drivers
AFTER UPDATE
ON `drivers`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF NEW.status = 1 THEN 
        INSERT INTO `active_drivers` (driver_id) VALUES (NEW.id);
    ELSE 
        DELETE FROM `active_drivers` WHERE driver_id = NEW.id;
    END IF;

END; //

DELIMITTER ;
```

Yo copie y pegué todo eso tal cual en la terminal y esto es lo que me devuelve:

```
> DELIMITTER //
>     -> 
>     -> CREATE TRIGGER update_active_drivers
>     -> AFTER UPDATE
>     -> ON `drivers`
>     -> FOR EACH ROW
>     -> BEGIN
>     ->
>     ->     IF NEW.status = 1 THEN
>     ->         INSERT INTO `active_drivers` (driver_id) VALUES (NEW.id); ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'DELIMITTER //
> 
> CREATE TRIGGER update_active_drivers AFTER UPDATE ON `drivers` FO' at
> line 1 MySQL [metro_cdmx]>     ELSE 
>     ->         DELETE FROM `active_drivers` WHERE driver_id = NEW.id; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'ELSE
>         DELETE FROM `active_drivers` WHERE driver_id = NEW.id' at line 1 MySQL [metro_cdmx]>     END IF; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line
> 1 MySQL [metro_cdmx]> MySQL [metro_cdmx]> END; // ERROR 1064 (42000):
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'END' at line 1
>     ->
>     -> DELIMITTER ;
```

Comment: agrega las comillas invertidas en `update_active_drivers`

Comment: Tu problema es que estás escribiendo `DELIMITTER` (con dos `T`), cuando la forma correcta es **`DELIMITER`** (con una sola `T`).

Comment: @A.Cedano  ay Dios... sí era eso. Muchisimas gracias, no creo que se me vuelva a pasar de ahora en más